# When to use adduser or useradd

Tags: command-line, adduser, useradd

The Question consist of three parts

1. What are the differences between them
2. When to use adduser or useradd
3. and why there is more than one command for the same purpose

Answer (score 3):

1. There is no difference in the functions provided, just that `useradd` is a compiled binary, and `adduser` is a perl script. `adduser` is more user-friendly, so it could fit better for a beginner.
2. Use `adduser` create a fully functional user on the system. The command will run tasks like creating home directory, creating a group for it, promting for password, etc. Beside that `useradd` will just create the user (ofcourse you can use switches, but the default is just the user creation).
3. The two commands are not identical (`adduser` runs `useradd` and many other things).

Answer (score 2):

**useradd** is native binary compiled with the system. But, **adduser** is a perl script which uses useradd binary in back-end.

**adduser** is more user friendly and interactive than its back-end **useradd**. There's no difference in features provided.

[SOURCE](https://superuser.com/questions/547966/whats-the-difference-between-adduser-and-useradd)